# Google App Engine application connection to a Third Party Cloud

Tags: java, mysql, database, google-app-engine, web-applications

According to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-third-party-databases) I should be able to connect my Google App Engine web application to an external database (in this case specifically, I want to connect it to heroku ClearCB-mysql).

```
"Other cloud providers
App Engine apps can connect to external databases that are hosted on other public clouds as
long as those database servers and your firewall are configured properly to accept
connections. Your App Engine app connects over the Internet using that external 
service's public IP address."
```

Can anyone point me to the proper configuration of serves and firewall? I can't find any documentation on it, and I don'e even have a clue where to start (I need explanation for dummies o_O) ;).

I am connecting to DB through spring-jpa, which works on localhost just fine, just when I upload my filed to Google App Engine it timesout.

---

ApplicationConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "dominikazb")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "dominikazb")
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return viewResolver;
}


@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "dominikazb" });

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    return em;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://hostname/databasename");
    dataSource.setUsername( "username" );
    dataSource.setPassword( "password" );
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return properties;
}
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int user_id;
private String username;
private String password;

//getters, setters and constructor

}
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String takeMeHome() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getall", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

pom.xml (relevant dependencies)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <version>8.0.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.0.pr3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone struggling with the same issue as I am. I found the answer in the Billing section of Google App Engine. What I mean is that I ran out of projects I could add to my Billing account, and for them connection to an external database was restricted. Once I uploaded my application to a project which had billing enabled, everything worked like a charm.